# Data Warning Slider Missing

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, settings, mobile-network, data-monitoring

I used to have 2 sliders, a warning slider & a limit slider, now just a limit slider is present.[image: ScreenShot after Warning Slider Missing]

Comment: Is data usage warning toggled on? Or did they remove that option too?

Comment: There never was a toggle for warning bar. I was sliding warning bar up to be as close as possible to limit bar when it disappeared.

Comment: So you were dragging it up and it disappeared? What happens if you drag the limit bar till you catch up with the other one?

Comment: It would only come within 5, 10, or 15 MB's of limit bar, depending on if usage was low or higher, and it would stop sliding. However, the last time I slid it up as close as it would go next to the limit bar it disappeared.

Comment: You can try clearing the data for the settings app. Settings > apps > settings > storage > clear data. Although that might not be worth it for what you're trying to do, as that will revert your settings to the original ones.